# clean multiple params in rails controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller action like this

```
def search
    if params[:latitude].present? && params[:longitude].present? && params[:longitude].strip != "" && params[:latitude].strip != ""
      room_address = Room.near([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]], 15, order: 'distance')
    elsif params[:location].present? && params[:location].strip != ""
      room_address = Room.near(params[:location], 15, order: 'distance')
    else
      return
    end

  end
```

As you can see am just  checking the presence of params by typing them one by one. Is there any better way??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
search_param = params[:location] || [params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]
room_address = Room.near(search_param, 15, order: 'distance')
```

You can also make sure that the params aren't coming in as empty strings by using front end validation instead of using  `.strip != ''` in your controller.

Comment: Or remove empty params by  `params.delete_if{|k,v| v.strip.blank?}` as before action if you don't want to deal with it in front end.